# jQuery UI Delay not work

Tags: function, button

why the delay doesn't work in this code?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
              show: { effect: 'fade', direction: "up" },
              hide: { effect: 'fade', direction: "down" },
         }).delay(1000).dialog( "close" );
         return false;
    });

 });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From [`.delay` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. **Only
>   subsequent events in a queue are delayed**; for example this will not
>   delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use
>   the effects queue.